# Print from a selected place in a array in c#

Tags: c#, arrays

Trying to write a short "program" that writes out witch day it is based on the week number the user put in.

```
String[] weekdays = { "Sunday", "Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday", "Thursday", "Saturday" };

Console.WriteLine("Write a day number");

//Here i want to print out the day number the user puts in. How?
Console.WriteLine();
```

Comment: Sunday being the day 1, what about accessing the `dayNumber - 1` index of `weekdays`?

Comment: Sounds like homework... Anyway, what have you done so far? And where exactly are you stuck?

Comment: What part are you having problems with? Do you not know how to read a specific indexed item out of an array? Do you not know how to get user input? Do you not know how to convert the string from user input into an int for use in the array index? Something else? Give us more specific details of what you are having problems with.

Comment: "Here i want to print out the day number the user puts in. How? Console.WriteLine();"  Yes.

Comment: or `Console.WriteLine((System.DayOfWeek)userNumber);`

Comment: Info from Microsoft: [Single-Dimensional Arrays (C# Programming Guide)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/arrays/single-dimensional-arrays), tutorialpoint: [C# - Arrays](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/csharp/csharp_arrays.htm), and [dot net perls](https://www.dotnetperls.com/array). And you will find many more with some googling

Answer (score 2):

```
String[] weekdays = { "Sunday", "Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday", "Thursday", "Saturday" };

Console.WriteLine("Write a day number");
var number = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

Console.WriteLine(weekdays[number]);
```

There is a lot of error checking missing here (what if the user enter "hello" or maybe -17?).

Generally speaking, you should consult your book before you ask such a question here. You are expected to do this research yourself.

Comment: Thanks, got it working now!

I got stuck on how to write from the array( weekdays[number] )

Have a great day!